# Vue.js + Vuetify Slider - Set min max and step values from Vue data

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My application requires approx. 20 paremeters to be submitted, most of these are numbers so I would like to use sliders with the preset `value`, `min`, `max` and `steps` being loaded in from somewhere else.

I'm storing these values as 2 objects in my Vue data - `SimulationParameters` and `SimulationParametersConfig`. So I have been able to get values out using something like:

```
<p> {{SimulationParameters.parameter1}} </p>
```

I have been using Vuetify's `v-slider` like so:

```
<v-slider class="customSlider" id="param1Slider"
    v-model="SimulationParameters.param1" 
    step="1" 
    min="0" 
    max="100">
</v-slider>
```

But now I want to be able to set the `min`, `max` and `step` values to those loaded in `SimulationParametersConfig`. I have tried the follwing variants:

```
step="SimulationParametersConfig.param1.step"
//takes it as a string - param1 = Nan
```

...

```
step={{SimulationParametersConfig.param1.step"}}
//failed to compile
```

...

```
step=SimulationParametersConfig.param1.step
//not sure but doesn't work
```

Is this possible to do this way? Or would it need to be done by a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind properties to components, [use `v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind), or its [shorthand `:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand).

So, to bind `step` to `SimulationParametersConfig.param1.step`, you would change:

```
<v-slider class="customSlider" id="param1Slider"
    v-model="SimulationParameters.param1" 
    step="1" 
    min="0" 
    max="100">
</v-slider>
```

To:

```
<v-slider class="customSlider" id="param1Slider"
    v-model="SimulationParameters.param1" 
    :step="SimulationParametersConfig.param1.step" 
    min="0" 
    max="100">
</v-slider>
```

Naturally, the same could be done to `min` and `max` as well.